# Code is not showing

Tags: support

I noticed that code added to question dissapears, look at my [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227122/error-in-getting-block-in-a-template). I had to wrap everything in code blocks AND quote blocks to display them.

Scroll down to `3.` and you will notice that the PHP Code is not showing, but if you click edit to edit the post, then you will see it.

Comment: really weired issue i just quoted that code and it shows but if we add code format to it then it is not showing :O

Comment: Any how, i have able to put the code syntax on your code:)

Comment: @AmitBera, I know, by using a workaround with the quote block like I did. But this is not a solution

Comment: Yes, it not a solution, i will look on later. Give a quick solution   for no

Answer (score 6):

This is because you put your code in a listing. Due to this, you need to intend the codes by 8 spaces.

This is not fixable since it is an ambiguity exists in the markdown language itself.

For more details, you can **[refer this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item)**.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I was Able to add block code in your question see `1.`

This is a weired situation where we need to add 2 or 3 more space to add like code block

May be @amit or @marius can check